# Term for a directed graph with unique paths

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, directed-graphs

My search has not turned up anything. Take a directed graph which satisfies that for any two vertices of the graph, there is at most one path connecting them. Is there a term for these sorts of graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such directed graphs have been called *singly connected* (for an example of this usage, see [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c85f/ddc73cf467827956078893f8edb5f183981c.pdf)).

But you should be careful, and define this term before using it, because other sources (such as Wikipedia) use the term synonomously with a *[polytree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytree)*: a directed graph whose underlying undirected graph is a tree.